# Letter head printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i have letter head design. Size is A4. I want to print in full bleed. How do I achieve with A 4 paper . If I take this design to print , it gives white margin out side the design.  I am using Adobe illustrator.

Comment: It's always a good idea to ask your printer for specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Print it on a bigger paper and trim it.

A commercial printer will buy a large sheet of paper and cut several pieces out of it, normally after they print several arranged like a "pattern".

They also can use special measures of paper, for example not an A2 paper, but a bigger size paper than A2 so they pull 4 A4 finished pieces.

Comment: Many printers also have oversized A4 and A3 papers

Comment: Yup, it is the same idea.